# Can I say that science "provides" beliefs?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

It seems to be relatively common to speak of "scientific beliefs". If I turn to science to inform myself about what it has to say on some topic, does science "provide" such beliefs? In other words: Is the following sentence awkward?

> "Science provides us with the best justified beliefs available on this matter."

If it is awkward, what would be an alternative? (I'd like to keep the term "beliefs" in favour of alternatives like "knowledge", "information" etc.)

Comment: Of course you can say. Like when you say : "the search provided them with several clues."

Comment: I apologize for philosophizing  here, but although it may be relatively common to say  "scientific beliefs", its almost an oxymoron - it's illogical. Science is almost the opposite of belief.  Belief is the acceptance that something is true without evidence. Science accepts nothing to be true without evidence. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: No apologies necessary since I am indeed intending to use the technical philosophical sense of the word "belief" (see https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/) which should be consistent with the common use of "scientific beliefs". This technical use is different from the one you are referring to. Without getting too much into details, this is also the reason why I'd like to stick with the term.

Comment: "scientific beliefs" seems more like common terminology, not something technical. When you get technical about "beliefs" and "science" you get into philosophical territory.  Also it could be argued science doesn't provide beliefs. Science provides explanations based on evidence. Perhaps that's how you should word it?

Comment: I think *belief* is the wrong word. It denotes an internal mental attitude about hypotheses or information. It isn't something that can be provided from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to come right out and say you can't provide a belief. You may provide something in which a person could believe, but it isn't a 'belief' at the point at which it is provided.

"Best justified" also sounds odd. What does that mean? People provide justification for all kinds of 'wrong' things. This sounds like you're saying the more you justify something, the more correct it is. You really need to grade the *quality* of the justification.

You might consider:

> Science provides the explanation with the most compelling evidence on this matter.